crear array de dias festivos desde base de datos
Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar con esto.. tengo un código el cual me saca del conteo entre dos fechas los días feriados, pero como estos días varían por años toca ir ingresándolos manualmente, en eso no hay problema, loq ue no me gustaria es ir agregandolos en el array (manteniendo esa estructura) si no que lo tome de una Tabla de la base de datos, es decir que yo pueda almacenarlos desde un administrador de la base de datos en ese formato..
la tabla de la BD seria: id-- ano- mes-- dia
pero no se como haria para trasformar los datos de alli almacenados a este array
// Guardamos en una variable los dias festivos en varios arrays con formato
// $dias_festivos[año][mes] = [dias festivos];
 $dias_festivos = array(
        "2020"=>array(11 => [2,16]),
        "2020"=>array(12 => [8,25]),
        "2021"=>array(1 => [1,11]),
        "2021"=>array(3 => [22]),
        "2021"=>array(4 => [1,2]),
        "2021"=>array(5 => [1,17]),
        "2021"=>array(6 => [7,14]),
        "2021"=>array(7 => [5,20]),
        "2021"=>array(8 => [7,16]),
        "2021"=>array(10 => [18]),
        "2021"=>array(11 => [1,15]),
        "2021"=>array(12 => [8,25]),
        //----------------------------------------------
        "2022"=>array(1 => [1,10]),
        "2022"=>array(3 => [21]),
        "2022"=>array(4 => [14,15]),
        "2022"=>array(5 => [1,30]),
        "2022"=>array(6 => [20,27]),
        "2022"=>array(7 => [4,20]),
        "2022"=>array(8 => [7,15]),
        "2022"=>array(10 => [17]),
        "2022"=>array(11 => [7,14]),
        "2022"=>array(12 => [8,25]),        
//---------------------------------------
        "2023"=>array(1 => [1,9]),
        "2023"=>array(3 => [20]),
        "2023"=>array(4 => [6,7]),
        "2023"=>array(5 => [1,22]),
        "2023"=>array(6 => [12,19]),
        "2023"=>array(7 => [3,20]),
        "2023"=>array(8 => [7,21]),
        "2023"=>array(10 => [16]),
        "2023"=>array(11 => [6,13]),
        "2023"=>array(12 => [8,25]),
//2024---------------------------------------
        "2024"=>array(1 => [1,8]),
        "2024"=>array(3 => [25,28,29]),
        "2024"=>array(5 => [1,13]),
        "2024"=>array(6 => [3,10]),
        "2024"=>array(7 => [1,20]),
        "2024"=>array(8 => [7,19]),
        "2024"=>array(10 => [14]),
        "2024"=>array(11 => [4,11]),
        "2024"=>array(12 => [8,25]),
);

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "usuario", "contrasena") or die("No se pudo conectar: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("basededatos");

// obtenemos el año actual -----
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$anoactual= date("Y");
//echo $anoactual;
//echo "<br>";

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT ano_festivos, mes_festivos, dia_festivos FROM festivos WHERE ano_festivos=$anoactual");

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf($fila[0], $fila[1], $fila[2]);
}

mysql_free_result($resultado);
?>


Hola Eduardo, ¿por qué te es útil que el año se repita? ¿no sería mejor que el año este una sola vez y que este contenga todos los meses y cada mes, sus días?

hola @Marcos gracias por responder, y como seria??, pues me toca indicar al ir grabando en la tabla el día mes y del año.. en un mes puede haber dos, tres dias, etc...

Me refería al arreglo en PHP, no a los datos en la tabla. ¿Ya sabes como conectarte a la BD? ¿Como recuperar datos de una tabla? Presiona [edit] y compartí el código que has intentado o que tengas hasta ahora.

listo pero no se por que no me resulta lo que llevo!!!!

Perfecto, ahora te vuelvo a pregunta ¿no sería mejor agrupar los años en lugar de repetirlos? o a lo sumo mostranos cómo utilizas actualmente la variable $dias_festivos? PD: la extensión mysql esta declarada obsoleta y se recomienda no utilizarla

Tal vez tengas razones por las cuales debes usar una base de datos. Yo tenía el mismo problema pero lo resolví usando funciones sin requerir el uso de una base de datos. Puedes verlo en: https://gist.github.com/jcvasquez07/2bcbcc8523c3c51745dfc0abd038b84a


IMPORANTE: PD: la extensión mysql está declarada obsoleta y se recomienda no utilizarla. Las alternativas a esta son:
mysqli y PDO

A partir de tu código podrías hacerlo así:
// ... código anterior
$anoactual= date("Y");
$dias_festivos = [];

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT ano_festivos, mes_festivos, dia_festivos FROM festivos WHERE ano_festivos=$anoactual");

// Obtenemos los datos como un arreglo asociativo
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $ano = $fila['ano_festivos'];
    $mes = $fila['mes_festivos'];
    $dia = $fila['dia_festivos'];

    // Verificamos si el año ya existe en el arreglo
    if (!isset($dias_festivos[$ano])) {
        $dias_festivos[$ano] = []; // Inicializamos el año
    }

    // Verificamos si el mes ya existe en el arreglo del año
    if (!isset($dias_festivos[$ano][$mes])) {
        $dias_festivos[$ano][$mes] = []; // Inicializamos el mes
    }

    // Agregamos el día
    $dias_festivos[$ano][$mes][] = $dia;
}

mysql_free_result($resultado);
var_export($dias_festivos);

Resultado:
array (
  2024 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 1,
      1 => 8,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 25,
      1 => 28,
      2 => 29,
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      0 => 1,
      1 => 13,
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      0 => 3,
      1 => 10,
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      0 => 1,
      1 => 20,
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      0 => 7,
      1 => 19,
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
      0 => 14,
    ),
    11 => 
    array (
      0 => 4,
      1 => 11,
    ),
    12 => 
    array (
      0 => 8,
      1 => 25,
    ),
  ),
)


Funciono Perfecto!!!! Mil gracias!!!
